# ImportError: cannot import name ceil_shift

Tags: python, importerror, shift, ceil

I'm receiving this error today, before was working perfectly.

```
ImportError: cannot import name ceil_shift
```

All i have is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python -W ignore::UserWarning
import urllib;
import urllib2;
import hashlib;
import simplejson as json;
import subprocess;
import smtplib;
from email.mime.multipart import MIMEMultipart
from email.mime.text import MIMEText
import ssh;
```

--- result:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./api.py", line 2, in <module>
    from maborak import maborak
  File "/root/automated/maborak.py", line 10, in <module>
    import ssh;
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ssh/__init__.py", line 62, in <module>
    from transport import SecurityOptions, Transport
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ssh/transport.py", line 33, in <module>
    from ssh import util
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ssh/util.py", line 33, in <module>
    from ssh.common import *
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/site-packages/ssh/common.py", line 98, in <module>
    from Crypto import Random
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/Crypto/Random/__init__.py", line 29, in <module>
    from Crypto.Random import _UserFriendlyRNG
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/Crypto/Random/_UserFriendlyRNG.py", line 38, in <module>
    from Crypto.Random.Fortuna import FortunaAccumulator
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/Crypto/Random/Fortuna/FortunaAccumulator.py", line 39, in <module>
    import FortunaGenerator
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/site-packages/Crypto/Random/Fortuna/FortunaGenerator.py", line 34, in <module>
    from Crypto.Util.number import ceil_shift, exact_log2, exact_div
ImportError: cannot import name ceil_shift
```

Its weird because the code was working 1 day ago.

thank you.

Comment: Thanks for adding your solution. I've rolled it back and copied it to an answer, to keep questions/answers separate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted on behalf of the OP:

The error was fixed with:

```
pip -v uninstall ssh
pip -v uninstall pycrypto

pip -v install pycrypto --upgrade
pip -v install ssh --upgrade
```